# I work in Three20 pictures it shows error message like this "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTURLRequestModel", referenced from :

Tags: iphone

i have a error message like this  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_TTURLRequestModel", referenced from: when i work in 320 picture.

Answer (score 0):

you have to link the 320 lib to your app

Answer (score 0):

I faced same problem, then I've simply deleted all three20 references from the project, re-
downloaded the source, and i've imported it using the new instruction